Can we send emails using VBA without using outlook running and without using SMTP methodology?
We have been VBA code to send emails using Smtp service but somehow Microsoft is treating it as spam and unable to receive it anymore.
So we have started using outlook app for sending email instead as mentioned in this thread (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-excel-vba-in-office-365-to-send-automated-e/f6b2042b-a17e-4aa4-99ea-f647b82cc8fd?page=2).
The problem with this approach is that outlook has to be opened/running. If not they just sit in outbox and keep wait until we open outlook. Is this an expected behavior and are there any other alternatives in VBA?
So we have started using outlook app for sending email instead as mentioned in this thread (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/use-excel-vba-in-office-365-to-send-automated-e/f6b2042b-a17e-4aa4-99ea-f647b82cc8fd?page=2).

"We have been VBA code to send emails using Smtp service but somehow Microsoft is treating it as spam and unable to receive it anymore." - How have you concluded that the SMTP protocol itself is specifically the problem here?

If the email goes into spam folder it may depend A LOT on the SMTP server used to send. Maybe it's not configured following the best practices that allows a good deliverability. Another issue could be the receiving server that may have a strict anti spam system. Another reason could be that your SMTP server ip/domain is listed somewhere...

You could create an instance of outlook if not open with CreateObject
But I prefere that the User opens outlook if needed:
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Sub DoOutlookStuff()
If Not IsOutlookOpen Then Exit Sub
' Your code here
End Sub

Function IsOutlookOpen() As Boolean
    Dim iHwnd As LongPtr, s As String
    Const classout As String = "rctrl_renwnd32"
    iHwnd = FindWindow(classout, s)
    If iHwnd > 0 Then
        IsOutlookOpen = True
    Else
    MsgBox "Please Open Outlook first"
    End If
End Function

